# How to Pause Executable if an Error is Encountered?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, executable

I googled for a solution for how to pause and executable is an error is encountered.  The most promising thing I found was this:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\ryans\dist\AS_to_GBQ.exe" %1
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%
```

I put that in my Command Prompt, and run it.  Now, the exe opens, runs, throws an error, and the exe shuts down with no indication of what actually happened.  How can I see the details of the error, or somehow troubleshoot this issue?  I'm on Windows 10.  I can run this as a batch file, or through PowerShell, if that helps.

Comment: Start your batchfile in an already opened command prompt. or put `pause` at the end.

Comment: I did start it in the open cmd prompt.  That's what the code above does.

Comment: What do you get when you run just the executable (with whatever argument you were passing to the script) in an already open Command Prompt? How were you invoking the batch script exactly? Please show that statement as well.

Comment: So, the 3 lines that I showed in my original post are what's being run in my Windows command prompt.  That's all I have at this point.  Is that NOT the correct way to do it?  Should I change things up to work in a batch script?  When I run the 3 lines listed above, all I get is a message that reads 'Failed to execute script As_to_GBQ'.  That's all I see.  I can't pause it, or open it, or control it in any way at all.

Comment: That is not an error message from CMD. What exactly is `AS_to_GBQ.exe`?

Comment: Also, do you actually want to pause the *executable* (as you wrote), or the *script* (after the executable failed)? While technically you can suspend processes, the only reasonable way to do the former would be by running it in a debugger.

Comment: I need to research this more.  I have a couple ideas of where to go from here.  Thanks for the feedback, everyone.

Comment: cmd prompt will not know the error code to the executable, it will either exit with 1 or 0. You say you run this from cmdline, but what do you add as the value for %1?